# Why have a LAN, why not just WANs everywhere

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, wan

I am new to learning about the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), and am looking into [what a LAN, MAN, and WAN are](https://kb.iu.edu/d/agki).

From [what I've seen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network):

> A local area network (LAN) is a computer network that interconnects computers within a limited area such as a residence, school, laboratory, university campus or office building. By contrast, a wide area network (WAN) not only covers a larger geographic distance, but also generally involves leased telecommunication circuits.

However, no reason is provided on why this distinction is made. I don't see why there needs to be a separation between LAN/MAN/WAN. Especially if LANs can use [Wi-Fi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) ([wireless LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_LAN)). I am unfamiliar with how Wi-Fi works, but it seems since it's not using wires that it is somehow similar to connecting to an AWS server from my local computer or phone over the internet (perhaps through satellites).

From not knowing anything about Wi-Fi/satellites/stations/etc., it seems that LAN could be the limitation similar to how radio stations are limited to areas in cities. Somehow the radio waves travel only a certain distance or something.

If that is the case, then there would be a need for [WANs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_area_network). But I don't see why not just use WANs everywhere instead of using LANs, there must be some advantage.

> A wide area network (WAN) is a telecommunications network or computer network that extends over a large geographical distance/place. Wide area networks are often established with leased telecommunication circuits.

But from what I see, a "leased telecommunication circuit" is simply:

> a [dedicated] telecommunication circuit, which is any line, conductor, or other conduit by which information is transmitted.

In addition:

> in terms of the application of computer networking protocols and concepts, it may be best to view WANs as computer networking technologies used to transmit data over long distances, and between different LANs, MANs and other localised computer networking architectures. This distinction stems from the fact that common LAN technologies operating at lower layers of the OSI model (such as the forms of Ethernet or Wi-Fi) are often designed for physically proximal networks, and thus cannot transmit data over tens, hundreds, or even thousands of miles or kilometres.

Again, I don't understand why there needs to be the distinction between LAN and WAN if LANs are so limited. I don't see why you can't be as efficient with a WAN as with a LAN.

For example, of Layer 2 of the OSI model, it states:

> Reliable transmission of data frames between two nodes connected by a physical layer.

But a Wi-Fi LAN isn't connected by a physical layer (like soldered together chips), so I don't understand.

I probably am missing a lot, so if this is a broad question maybe it would be helpful to know where to look for more information. Thank you.

Comment: because you don't have enough IP addresses if everyone has a public IPv4 address, and not everyone needs internet access

Comment: I'm interested to see what people make of this one. There are a lot of reasons, more than I'm qualified to enumerate. Lack of IPv4 addresses is just the start. Security is the next; any chain is as strong as its weakest link... but if all links are directly connected, security goes out the window.

Comment: @phuclv LANs have existed long before NAT or IP address exhaustion. // I feel the easiest method to segment networks is responsibility. Is it yours? Probably LAN (WLAN is also LAN). Is it an ISPs? Probably WAN.

Comment: There are a lot of wrong assumptions in this question. It's probably too broad for someone to try to correct all your misconceptions and it would take a couple book chapters at least to clear up all your confusion. I don't mean to say any of that in a rude way so don't take it wrong. You might do well to buy a Comptia Network+ book and study that a bit.

Comment: Well, that all being said this topic is probably better suited for [chat]. You have enough rep, so ask away!

Comment: @DanielB I just asked on the home page of [ask a superuser moderator](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator), not sure if that's the right place.

Comment: That's not going to be the right chat. That's specifically for questions about the moderation of this site. [Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) is the main chat room for this site. Not sure if they take this type of detailed question in there since it's more of a lounge type atmosphere but you could pop in there and just kind of ask if it's an appropriate topic to ask about first.

Comment: I always think so: LAN is a network with a single administration center; MAN is a network with several centers, but a single administration policy; WAN is a network without a single administration policy, which is united only by common protocols and standards. Personally, this is quite enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every system on a LAN is directly connected to one another.

Before you say "no, they aren't" ...

- In the old days of networking, this was literally a single physical cable to which all computers were connected (10BaseT, thinnet, thicknet, etc.)
- Hubs/concentrators/switches were developed that allowed computers in a network to connect to a switch, instead of physically on the same wire.  The switch still physically connects computers in the same way - two computers separated by a switch talk to each other the same way as if they were connected by a common wire (Omitting talk about "collisions" for simplicity)
- A concept in networking exists called "bridging" that allows two different networking technologies to be directly connected - think of it like a 2 port switch where 1 end is Ethernet and the other end is something like fiber optic or Token Ring if you want to go that far back.  Systems on either end of the bridge talk in the same way as though the bridge was simply a wire between them.
- On your home wireless router, your wireless LAN is "bridged" in the same way conceptually - so it's still directly connected - WLAN traffic hits a bridge in your home router which is then forwarded over the internal 4-port LAN switch of your router.  Systems on either end of this wireless bridge talk in the same way as though the bridge was simply a wire between them.

If everything is directly connected, i.e. on the same LAN (WLAN = LAN) - then a router is not needed for two systems to talk.  Don't confuse this with the 4 port *switch* to which your wireless hardware is *bridged* on your home router - this switch/bridge is one part of that device that also does routing.

When two systems that want to talk are on the same LAN, bridged/switched/however that happens, systems can simply output IP packets from their NICs and the receiving system will get them.  Very simple.  The system can also send out a broadcast packet which will reach all systems on the LAN.

When you are not on the same LAN, a router is needed - and the sending system has to send what it wants to say to remote system to the router, which is responsible for forwarding back and forth between the networks.  Routers don't forward broadcast packets for obvious reasons.

The name "Internet" comes from the core protocol driving it - IP, which is the "Internetworking Protocol."  It's explicit goal is to allow communication between networks - between places that already have many systems.  Routers handle the actual communication between networks.

Now that you understand how it all works, the real reason for the divisions:

- Ethernet broadcast traffic shouldn't go out to every system in the world.
- If two systems in the same network or near each other have to go through the WAN to talk to each other, it's inefficient (but great for data collection and middle-man companies).
- WAN is controlled by the ISP.  LAN is controlled by me.  I can connect as many computers/devices as I want to my own LAN and not have to ask anyone.

Cell phones already work on a "ISP gives you a new line for each device" and "Two systems near each other go through the WAN to talk to each other" model.  The limiting factor in this taking over all Internet connections is the fact that wired connections are many times faster, especially for businesses.

Perhaps this is how things will be for all consumer Internet in the future, but unless cellular technology starts matching speed of really fast wired business connections (might happen soon), it's unlikely.

Answer (score 5):

> However, no reason is provided on why this distinction is made. I don't see why there needs to be a separation between LAN/MAN/WAN. Especially if LANs can use Wi-Fi (wireless LAN). I am unfamiliar with how Wi-Fi works, but it seems since it's not using wires that it is somehow similar to connecting to an AWS server from my local computer or phone over the internet (perhaps through satellites).

Whether it uses wires or doesn't has nothing to do with it being a LAN. It's more about the area covered – and as @Akina mentioned in their comment, about the management structure.

(Although the distinction is a bit fuzzy. An international corporation could have its own private worldwide network with a single administration, which could be called either a LAN or a WAN depending on how you squint.)

> A wide area network (WAN) is a telecommunications network or computer network that extends over a large geographical distance/place. Wide area networks are often established with leased telecommunication circuits.

I guess "leased lines" had a more specific meaning – they were pretty much telephone lines, except directly connecting two modems together (dialup modems, not DSL nor cable modems).

> I don't understand why there needs to be the distinction between LAN and WAN if LANs are so limited.

But that's exactly what creates the distinction.

> I don't see why you can't be as efficient with a WAN as with a LAN.

These days, generally, you can (at least as far as bandwidth goes). The largest WAN – the Internet – transfers petabytes of data per day. Individual backbone links go up to 100 Gbps of capacity.

Though it could be that when your reading material was written, the cost differences between a 100 Mbps local link (from room to room) and a 100 Mbps international link were much more significant.

But on the other hand, in the earlier days, sometimes the whole country had just a 64 kbps or 1 Mbps link to the world – because the technology just wasn't available yet.

> But a Wi-Fi LAN isn't connected by a physical layer (like soldered together chips), so I don't understand.

Radio waves are a physical layer. Optical signals are a physical layer. "Physical" doesn't mean "tangible", it means something that directly deals with the laws of physics.

---

From comments:

> because you don't have enough IP addresses if everyone has a public IPv4 address, and not everyone needs internet access

While not wrong, this comment refers to a *completely different* distinction between "LAN" and "WAN". There can be home LANs using global addresses, and worldwide networks using private addresses.

(For example, an IPv6 LAN can very cheaply use the same addressing format as the rest of the internet. If you happen to own a decent chunk of IPv4 addresses, you're completely free to use them in your LAN as well – see MIT as an example.)

Answer (score 1):

You try to bite too much in one time. I am not surprised you are confused.

For very crude divide: Your home network with one or multiple computers, is a LAN network. From your router to the telephone company is a MAN network. From there to the World, it is a WAN.

That question series is very large to go it through in detail, but here are some points. 
This distinction has made in the early days of telecommunications and Internet technologies. All new Wi-fis were not even invented.

1) So one answer is: for historical reasons.

WANs , MANs, and LANs tend to have a different kind of structure. There is one book, which deals this very thoroughly, but it is a very stressfull and complicated book too, not recommending this, but here it is, Fred Halsall:Data Communications, Computer Networks and Open Systems.

What I do, recommend is: Andrew S. Tanenbaum's books for example: Internetworking. It is much more reader-friendly. MANs and LANs, uses different IP-address spaces. These networks are hierarchical. Nowadays they are using IPv6 addresses, even you see IPv4 addresses in your everyday life connections.

2) Second answer is: for a network topology and hierarchy and a different set of IP-address space.

Because, like you have read, LANs have very different properties compared for example WAN-networks, which are usually very large inter-continental connections. You do not need to know every detail about WAN or MAN connections, unless you are working in some Internet Service Provider (ISP) like telephone company.

3) Third answer is: different properties.

Comment: But I need to emphasize, this lacks a huge amount of details, and I am not so talented wizard to know all combinations of network structures and hierarchies. Especially newer ones :)

Comment: I checked the Fred Halsall's book. Indeed there is only three pages in the whole 900-page opus, which deals about MAN networks (within same context  than a ATM and  a DQDB techniques) according to index. So I think, there is really only WAN and LAN networks common in real life. The MAN network seems to be some kind of abstract term.

Comment: So a very crude divide turns to be:  LAN (Home network) and WAN ( ISP provider, for example telephone company).